# How to map partial keys of a Map to Bean fields with Dozer or Orika?

Tags: java, mapping, dozer, orika

My goal is to map a large flat file to a bean. Example of that's inside the file as follows.

Flat file, which is read to a `HashMap` as key-value pairs:

```
addressname=the name
addressstreet=the street
addresszip=12345
addresstown=the town
addressmail=the@mail.com
personage=14
personname=
//many more fields...
```

Target bean:

```
public class Address {
    private String name, street, zip, town, mail;
}
```

Question: which mapping framework (dozer, orika) offers partial mapping of the `HashMap` key?

Maybe the following pseudocode is possible in any framework:

```
-> if any key starts with "address"
-> split (eg to address.name, address.street)
-> take 1st part as field name of an object, and 2nd part as nested property.
```

Or:
Define some kind of suffix that represents always the property of a nested object: `` `address{suffix}` -> map to class `address.{fieldname}` ``.

Is one of the mapping frameworks capable of it?

Comment: I'm aware that dozer isn't capable of reading suffixes.